# Strange behaviours of responsive menu

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I created website with responsive menu for PC-browser and Android-browser for Samsung S5 using

```
@media screen 
and (device-width: 360px) 
and (device-height: 640px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
```

Menu works only on PC. When website is running on mobile browser (native and chrome also) then .menu block seems to get wanted size but is still invisible, although there is no display: none.

[image]

I used z-index for solving my problem but nothing happend and still i can't find bug. When .content display is set on hide, then .menu looks ok. Div .menu seems to be underside(?) of .content but if does, then why z-index doesn't work correctly?

This is this site [Website](http://jedendzien.pl/). Can somebody check that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found problem. Height of **.navigator** was set on **3em**. Div **.menu** was inside **.navitagor**